# Separate local network traffic from WAN traffic via different NICs

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, routing

I own a Mac running 10.13.6. In my house, due to the use of various PowerLine adapters, WiFi is *way* faster for Internet / outbound traffic, but Ethernet is still faster for local traffic (at least some of it, especially NAS and the like).

I'd like to tell my Mac to route all internal (192.168.0.x) traffic through my Ethernet NIC, and all the rest via WiFi.

How can I accomplish this?

*Alternatively*, can I route only specific local IPs through Ethernet? Or implement some kind of routing metric so that my Mac automatically switches to Ethernet (faster) when not talking to the outside?

Thanks in advance!